# Array and Object hybrid?

Tags: javascript

I played around with the Object.assign function and found out that i can create an array object fusion kinda?

the code looks like this:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3]
Object.assign(list, {property: true})
```

the list appears in brackets when i log it and i can still access the 1 with `list[0]`, BUT I can also access the true by logging `list.property` and when i log `typeof list` i get and Object.

I'm really confused rn, can someone explain to me what `list` is and why this happens?
Thank you :)

Comment: In JavaScript, arrays **are** objects. Think about the `.length` property

Comment: arrays are [*exotic objects*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#exotic-object) ... with pineapple ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`list` is an array, which is an object. Standard arrays in JavaScript are objects, not the contiguous blocks of memory divided into fixed-size elements that they are in most programming languages. They have their own literal form, they inherit from `Array.prototype`, and they have a `length` property that adjusts itself if you increase their size (and that can remove entries if you assign to it), but other than that they're just objects. You can add non-entry properties to them, as you've discovered, because they're just objects.

Here's a simpler example:

```js
const a = [];
a.example = "hi there";
console.log(a.example); // "hi there"
```

In fact, what you think of as array indexes are actually property names, and they're strings. Example:

```js
const a = ["zero"];
for (const index in a) {
    console.log(index + " (" + typeof index + ")");
}
```

A property name is considered an array index if it meets [certain criteria](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type):

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see [7.1.21](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-canonicalnumericindexstring)) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive [integer](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#integer) ≤ 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. An *array index* is an integer index whose numeric value *i* is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

We typically write them as numbers, and JavaScript engines optimize, but in specification terms they're strings. :-)

> the list appears in brackets when i log it

Typically, when you log something with a console, the console looks at it to see what it is and then bases its output on that. With most consoles, when you log an array, they just log the array entries without showing you the other properties. (That's also what you get when you use `JSON.stringify`, since JSON arrays can't have non-entry properties.) But the property *is* there, as you saw. You can also see it in `for-in` loops, since `for-in` loops through the properties of the object, not the entries of the array:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];
Object.assign(list, {property: true});
for (const key in list) {
    console.log(`${key} = ${list[key]}`);
}
```

Comment: but i can't seem to add the property: true to the array if i define it normally

Comment: @AtillaCesur - What is your code for doing that?

Comment: like i would define an object (or array) typically so: `var list = [1, 2, 3, property: true]`

Comment: @AtillaCesur - Array literal syntax only lets you create array entries, not other kinds of properties. You can only add other kinds of properties to arrays after creating them. (It used to be similar for object literals, there were some things you could only do after-the-fact, but recent versions of JavaScript have added syntax for them. I doubt we'll get syntax for properties in array literals, but personally I like the idea.)

Comment: thanks, I understand now :)